# Function That Returns Capitalized Initials of Name

Tags: python, list, function, methods, indexing

I created a Python function that takes an argument, fullname, gets fullname's initials and prints them out capitalized. But there's a problem with my code - it only works with two names. It breaks if the fullname has a middle name, i.e. Daniel Day Lewis.

Here is what I tried:

```
def get_initials(fullname):
    xs = (fullname)
    name_list = xs.split()

    print(name_list)

#Given a person's name, return the person's initials (uppercase)

    first = name_list[0][0]
    second = name_list[1][0]

    return(first.upper() + second.upper())

answer = get_initials("Ozzie Smith")
print("The initials of 'Ozzie Smith' are", answer)
```

Obviously this attempt only includes two variables, one for the first name and one for the second name. If I add a third variable, like this:

```
def get_initials(fullname):
    xs = (fullname)
    name_list = xs.split()

    print(name_list)

#Given a person's name, return the person's initials (uppercase)

    first = name_list[0][0]
    second = name_list[1][0]
    third = name_list[2][0]
    return(first.upper() + second.upper() + third.upper())

answer = get_initials("Ozzie Smith")
print("The initials of 'Ozzie Smith' are", answer)
```

I get:

```
IndexError: list index out of range on line 10
```

(which is the line)

```
third = name_list[2][0]
```

Of course this function does work if I change fullname to "Ozzie Smith Jr". But my function has to work regardless of whether there are 1, 2, 3, or 4 names in fullname. I need to say something like:

```
def get_initials(fullname):
    xs = (fullname)
    name_list = xs.split()

    print(name_list)

#Given a person's name, return the person's initials (uppercase)

    first = name_list[0][0]

    #if fullname has a second name: 
    second = name_list[1][0]

    #if fullname has a third name: 
    third = name_list[2][0]

    #if fullname has one name:
    return(first.upper())

    #if fullname has two names:
    return(first.upper() + second.upper())

    #if fullname has three names:
    return(first.upper() + second.upper() + third.upper())

    #if fullname has three names:
    return(first.upper() + second.upper() + third.upper + fourth.upper())

answer = get_initials("Ozzie Smith")
print("The initials of 'Ozzie Smith' are", answer)
```

How do I say "if fullname has a second name or third name or fourth name, return the uppercase initial" in Python? Or am I on the right track? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like:

```
def get_initials(fullname):
  xs = (fullname)
  name_list = xs.split()

  initials = ""

  for name in name_list:  # go through each name
    initials += name[0].upper()  # append the initial

  return initials
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to append the initials like that. Can you explain why "for name in name_list:" goes through each name as opposed to each letter?

Comment: It's because the `xs.split()` function will return a `list` rather than a string so that `name_list` equals `["John", "Smith"]`. Therefore the `for name in name_list` statement goes through the list items one by one rather than each of the the letters in the string

Answer (score 13):

You can make use of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
s = ''.join([x[0].upper() for x in fullname.split(' ')])
```

---

**edit**: should probably explain a little more
list comprehensions allow you to build a list as you iterate.
So first we build a list by splitting fullname with a space `fullname.split(' ')`. As we get those values, we take the fist letter `x[0]` and uppercase it `.upper()`. Finally we join the list into one with no spaces `''.join(...)`.

This is a nice one liner that's really fast and will pop up in various forms as you continue working with python.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation - makes sense. Good to know.

Comment: If the full name contains 2 consecutive spaces this will fail. I've used this successfully: `''.join([x[0].upper() for x in filter(None, fullname.split(' '))])`

Answer (score 3):

This is my answer:

1. Splitting the string into a list
2. Iterate through elements using `range` and `i`
3. Taking index 0 for each element during iteration (Hence `words[i][0]`)
4. `words[i][0].upper` for the upper case requirement for the question

```
def initials(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(words)):
        result += words[i][0].upper()
    return result
    
print(initials("Universal Serial Bus")) # Should be: USB
print(initials("local area network")) # Should be: LAN
print(initials("Operating system")) # Should be: OS
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
map(str.upper, zip(*the_persons_name.split())[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

the other variance of one liner as below, we can join all the initials 1st then do the `upper` 1 shot at last

```
''.join(i[0] for i in a.split()).upper()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def initials(name):
    words = name.split()
    result = "" 
    for word in words:
        result += word[0].upper()
    return result
```